# Split by uppercase only if the next character is a lowercase

Tags: php, regex, string

I am trying to split a string like :"ThisIsA STRING"

I want it splitted like this :"This Is A STRING"

My current regex gives me the following result :"This Is A S T R I N G"

```
$filname_desc = preg_replace('/([a-z0-9])?([A-Z])/','$1 $2',$filname_desc);
```

Is it possible to modify the regex to only split if the following character is a lowercase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
php> $str = "ThisIsA STRING"
php> echo preg_replace('/([a-z])([A-Z])/','$1 $2', $str)
This Is A STRING
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$filname_desc = preg_replace('/([a-z0-9]+)?([A-Z]+)/','$1 $2',$filname_desc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$filname_desc = preg_replace('/([a-z0-9])(?=[A-Z])/','$1 ',$filname_desc);
```

`[a-z0-9]` matches only if it is followed by `[A-Z]`.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/DwGxIWvh)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '?' symbol between the brackets.